# How to get the public path of an Amazon Object?

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm currently listing my root objects as:

```
var files = new List<string>();
var request = new ListObjectsRequest();
request.WithBucketName(bucketName);

try
{
    using (AmazonS3 client = Amazon.AWSClientFactory.CreateAmazonS3Client(this.accessKey, this.secretAccessKey))
    using (ListObjectsResponse r = client.ListObjects(request))
        foreach (var o in r.S3Objects)
            //o.ETag, o.Key, o.StorageClass, o.Size
            if (o.Size > 0)
                files.Add(o.Key); 
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // log exception
}
```

in `o.Key` there's the file name, but **I would like to get the public path** for this file name and I don't seam to find help on getting such reference to an existing file.

I normally use the **Public Bucket** url inside the configuration file, but I was wondering if I can avoid such configuration and actually get that from the Object itself upon retrieval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found out that is a little easier as Amazon S3 follows a convention:

```
string path = String.Format("http://{0}.s3.amazonaws.com/", originBucketName);
```

this will be the public path.